Testing of a ChatGPT LLM application using JMeter
FYI, I am a developer not a tester. I need to do load testing on my ChatGPT. I have installed WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch. I have first created a thread group initially with number of users 1, ramp-up 1 sec, and loop count 1. Then I have added “WebSocket Open Connection" sampler and got the below response. I think the connection was done.

Now I have to ask my ChatGPT a question. So, I added “WebSocket Single Write” sampler with existing connection. I selected Data as Text and in the Request data I asked the question.

Now to get the response back from the ChatGPT I added “WebSocket Single Read” sampler with existing connection.

In the Listener’s View Results Tree, I did not get the complete response/answer from the ChatGPT. As you can see below {"status":"streaming","content":"I"} The content is “I” which is only one character. I should get the full response or paragraph to that question but not getting it neither I am getting error.

Please find below the sampler’s connection that I have added.

How should I get the full answer in the Response Body from my ChatGPT. I also need to perform load testing by increasing number of users with different prompts as well. Please guide me through this. Thanks in advance.

Qualifying question:  Are you testing the live internet-based version of ChatGPT or a local installed instance?

Thanks James for asking. This is our own implemented ChatGPT which is live internet-based. It internally calls GPT3.5. Actually it is working fine when I ask question to him in UI. But here in Jmeter tool when I ask question then in the response I get only the first word of answer. For example I ask "Who created you?" the answer on UI is "I was created by a company." But here in Jmeter it is giving me only the first word "I" as answer. Another example I asked "what comes after Sunday?" the on UI the answer is "Monday" same answer I got on Jmeter tool.

Since it is a single word answer hence I got it correct in Jmeter as well. I need to do looping or something in jmeter plugin/sampler to get the complete answer? @JamesPulley

@SachinSinkar Have you tried using “WebSocket request-response Sampler" ?

If you only get part of the (expected) response, it might be the case that the response is fragmented into several frames. The websocket-sampler will only read one frame, if there are more you'll have to setup a loop to read them all. You can find out whether fragmentation is used by enabling the samplers debug logging by adding the next line to log4j2.xml file:
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
Samplers reading a frame will log whether the received frame is a "normal" single frame, a non-final frame (i.e. 1st fragment), a continuation frame or a final continuation frame (last fragment).
The websocket plugin provides a JMeter variable called websocket.last_frame_final that indicates whether the last frame read was final, that can be used to setup the loop that reads all frames of a message.
See the websocket samplers docs for more info on fragments and how the samplers handle them.

Thanks Peter, Now I have added a loop controller plugin, in that I have given Loop Count: 10 but it is hard coded. If I change the question to chatgpt whose answer is more than 10 tokens then this loop count will give me only first 10 tokens as response. I need to stop executing this loop at this response {"status":"done","content":"2024-06-03T13:12:40.910721"} so that only the response is captured and not this {"status":"error","content":"Previous task still running"}. I have tried to apply 'if controller' 'while controller' as well by specifying ! ${websocket.last_frame_final} condition.

Did you check the server response is fragmented?

I added  to log4j2.xml file and got this below log.
DEBUG e.l.j.w.RequestResponseWebSocketSampler: Sampler 'WebSocket request-response Sampler' received text frame with text: '{"status":"streaming","content":"I"}'
2024-06-06 20:29:22,326 DEBUG e.l.j.w.RequestResponseWebSocketSampler: Sampler 'WebSocket request-response Sampler' received text frame with text: '{"status":"streaming","content":" was"}'
Till user/thread 25 I didn't get any fail sampler. But for 30 users I get 3 failed samplers, for 100 I got 75 failed, 500 I got 1500 failed samplers.

So, from the logging we learn that the response are not fragmented, so that is not the problem. That explains why the loop with ! ${websocket.last_frame_final} condition does not work.
Hence, the problem you face is that the server splits the response in a number of (normal) text messages. The solution is to create a while loop with as end condition that the received message contains "status": "done". This can be done with standard JMeter constructs.

Now I am getting this error for websocket request-response sampler, when I set ramp-up period of 300 sec for 500 threads.
Response message:Sampler error: java.lang.ClassCastException: class eu.luminis.websocket.PingFrame cannot be cast to class eu.luminis.websocket.DataFrame (eu.luminis.websocket.PingFrame and eu.luminis.websocket.DataFrame are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.jmeter.DynamicClassLoader @548c4f57)
Is there any version mismatch issue between Jmeter and Websocket plugins?
Please suggest me something.

(1) add a Frame Filter to ignore Ping frames and (2) open a issue in the plugin bitbucket repo with a complete stacktrace of the exception
